# React Native IOS app build error: File ios/DerivedData/ReactNativeStarter/......../ReactNativeStarter.app/main.jsbundle does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm building React Native IOS application.
It's working on debug mode on simulator.

```
yarn run:ios // this is working
```

Also running on XCode is also working.
but when I'm gonna publish to appstore, it's getting this issue.

```
File Project_Path/ios/DerivedData/ReactNativeStarter/ArchiveIntermediates/ReactNativeStarter/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReactNativeStarter.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
```

Also it's opening metro terminal.
It's showing this issue.

```
metro-file-map: Haste module naming collision: cliui
  The following files share their name; please adjust your hasteImpl:
    * <rootDir>/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeStarter.app/package.json
    * <rootDir>/ios/DerivedData/ReactNativeStarter/ArchiveIntermediates/ReactNativeStarter/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ReactNativeStarter.app/package.json

Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:450:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:507:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 633)
    at async HasteMap._applyFileDelta (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:672:7)
    at async /Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:327:9
    at async DependencyGraph.ready (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:95:5)
    at async Bundler.ready (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:69:5)
    at async IncrementalBundler.ready (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:289:5)
    at async Server.ready (/Users/admin/Downloads/ProjectRootPath/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1085:5) {
  mockPath1: 'ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeStarter.app/package.json',
  mockPath2: 'ios/DerivedData/ReactNativeStarter/ArchiveIntermediates/ReactNativeStarter/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ReactNativeStarter.app/package.json'
}

Metro is ready.
```

react-native version 0.72.2

Anyone help this issue?

I'm building React Native IOS application.
It's working on debug mode on simulator.